# Prevent Javascript from escaping special character

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, concatenation, href

This may sound like a silly query. That said, I have looked all over for an answer and still cannot figure this out.

I am trying to build a dynamic link using JS, but JS keeps escaping the "/"

**Here is my code:**

```
var permalink = 'http://yvannasr.com/events';
var slug = 'run-1';
var name = 'run 1';

var link = "<a href=" + "'"+ permalink + "/" + slug +"/" +"'"+">
```

**Here is the output I am getting for the link variable:**

```
<a href=" http:="" yvannasr.com="" events="" run-1="" '="">
```

**This is what i would like the output to be:**

```
<a href="http://yvannasr.com/events/run-1/">
```

Could anyone let me know what i am doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Yvan

Comment: If you want to output `"` inside a `"     "` (string), escape it using `\"` inside the string - `"http://\"wwww\""`

Comment: Seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/68sqaf0c/1/

Comment: works fine for me.  Just add double quote (") after your last bracket ... var link = "<a href=" + "'" + permalink + "/" + slug + "/" + "'" + ">";

Comment: You seem to have an extra set of `"` somewhere. I would suggest running the debugger and inspect each variable to ensure you don't have an extra quote or double quote somewhere. Running `var link = "<a href='" + permalink + "/" + slug +"/" +"'>"` in my console gives the correct string. So the problem is probably in the variables whatever they might actually be.

Comment: I think you're getting messed up concatenating literal strings. Just put everything that's not a variable in the same string, like this: `var link = "<a href='" + permalink + "/" + slug + "/'>"`. Note that I'm doing `href=` followed by single quote, followed by double quote, in case that's hard to read.

Comment: Code is fine, except for the obvious missing double quote. But there is no way that the value is as reported in the question.

Comment: How do you output the *link* variable? It seems like it is being parsed before getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct in your syntax, but with a small change of missing a closing " (doublequotes) in setting the "link" variable.
Possibly when you render the above "link" variable as HTML you should get a similar structure as you have mentioned in your output because of a missing closing tag.

You should be good with the following line

```
var link = "<a href=" + "'"+ permalink + "/" + slug +"/" +"'"+">"
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: First off, your assignment of a string to variable `link` has bad syntax. You cannot add a `"` character at the end the way you are. If you want to add that character, you should use `'\"'`, because the backslash escapes the double-quote, allowing it to be used as a normal character.

I don't see how your code can possibly make the result you posted. Especially with the equals signs all over the place; it makes no sense to me.

When I run this code:

`var x = "http://www.google.com"; x;`

The result is:

`"http://www.google.com"`

The forward slash can be used in strings without any escaping or workaround.